# JQuery-PAge load

Tags: jquery

Upon page reload, all the nodes expand and then only the selected node
remain expanded which is the desired behavior. However, I'd like to
prevent all the nodes from expanding upon refresh as it creates a
flicker. Has anyone else experience this behaviour? How can I turn it
off?

Thanks

Comment: well, a bit more information might be helpfull. Which nodes? Do you treat those "nodes" somewhere?

Comment: Not a node,it question and answer.when click on question,answer will display

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing then hiding, hide then show.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should hide them from the start using CSS better than Javascript. If you can't (depending on your app fonctionnality or else), you can hide every item at page load and just expand the one you want. The rendering will be better I guess.

Answer (score 0):

quick & dirty example:

[http://jsbin.com/iyika3/edit](http://jsbin.com/iyika3/2/edit)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
   $('ul > li').toggle(function(){
     $(this).find('ul').slideDown('fast');
   }, function(){
     $(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast');
   });
 });​
```